# Multiply each element of a vector by each element of another vector

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I have two very big column vectors, `A` and `B`, of size `ax1` and `bx1`, respectively. I want to construct a vector `C` of size `(b*a)x1` by computing `A(i)*B(j)` for each `i` and `j`. To illustrate what I mean:

```
clear
a=10^3;
b=10^3;
A=randn(a,1);
B=randn(b,1);
Ctemp=zeros(a,b);
for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        Ctemp(i,j)=A(i)*B(j);
    end
end
C=reshape(Ctemp, a*b,1);
```

**Question:** is there a more efficient way to obtain `C` which avoid double looping? My actual `a` and `b` are bigger than `10^3`.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? If you use array-multiply (`.*` or `bsxfun(@times, ...`) and provide a column vector (e.g. `a`-by-1) and a row vector (e.g. 1-by-`b`) you can get the result you want (of size a*b), up to transpose/`reshape`.

Comment: Thanks. If I do `A.*B` I get `C` with `C(i)=A(i)*B(i)`. I have Matlab 2017b but I would like something working also on Matlab 2015b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple case of array multiplication that can benefit from implicit (or explicit) expansion:

```
% Implicit (R2016b and newer):
C = A(:) .* B(:).'; % optionally surround by reshape( ... , [], 1);

% "Explicit" (R2007a and newer):
C = bsxfun( @times, A(:), B(:).' );
```

From there it's just a matter of reshaping, as you're already doing (`D = C(:)` or `D = C(:).'`).

Answer (score 3):

You can also calculate the outer product of the vectors, resulting in a matrix of your required terms:

```
C = A*B'; % Assuming A,B are column vectors here
```

And reshape the output afterward as stated. Not sure if more efficient though.

Comment: Instead of assuming the shape, you can force them to be columns using `(:)`. Also, note that `transpose` is `.'` and **not** `'` (which is **conjugate** transpose).